# Invariant Violation - Element type is invalid - Expected a string but got object

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Here is one of my codes in a react native project. It uses `react-navigation` version 2 in various places.

```
render() {
        const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
            Login: {
                screen: LoginScreen
            },
            SelectInstance: {
                screen: SelectInstanceScreen
            },
            ForgotPassword: {
                screen: ForgotPasswordScreen
            },
            App: {
                screen: AppScreen
            }
        }, {
            initialRouteName: this.state.initialRoute,
            headerMode: 'none',
            navigationOptions: {
                headerVisible: false,
            },
            cardStyle:{backgroundColor:'white'}
        });

        let view;
        if (this.state.initialRoute === '') {
            view = <Spinner
                visible={true}
                color={"#f88220"}
            />
        } else {
            view = <StackNavigator/>;
        }

        return (
            view
        )
    }
```

The problem is, if the  block is running it throws an error as

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid
Expected a string(for built-in components) but got: object
Check the render method of 'SceneView'
```

This only happens on my iOS build. Android build works just fine. Can anyone help with much more iOS experience?

PS - I have debugged the app in various ways. createStackNavigator is the exact place with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question since I managed to get through the situation.

I found out that the versions I were using caused this problem. I was using react-native 0.54.0. Then I upgraded to following versions and the errors were gone.

```
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.2",
"react-navigation": "^2.17.0"
```

Hope this helps someone.